# How to tell typescript that an argument is definitely an array when allowing both a string and an array of strings

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering how to let typescript know that the code is functionally valid.

It's saying it could be a string, when I'm really unsure how that would be possible. Is this a bug? Or am I just typing something incorrectly?

Example:

```
const i18nInstance = {
    options: {defaultNS: 'common'}
}

const getInitialProps = (req: any, namespaces?: string | string[]) => {
  if (!namespaces) {
    namespaces = i18nInstance.options.defaultNS
  }
  if (typeof namespaces === 'string') {
    namespaces = [namespaces]
  }

  const initialI18nStore = req.i18n.languages.reduce((langs, lang) => {

    // typescript thinks namespaces could be a string, but it obviously will never be.

    langs[lang] = namespaces.reduce((ns, n) => {
      ns[n] = (req.i18n.services.resourceStore.data[lang] || {})[ns] || {}
      return ns
    }, {})
    return langs
  }, {})

  return {
    i18n: req.i18n,
    initialI18nStore,
    initialLanguage: req.i18n.language,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make compiler be sure that it is arry of strings.

```
const getInitialProps = (req: any, namespaces?: string | string[]) => {
  if (!namespaces) {
    namespaces = 'default';
  }
  if (typeof namespaces === 'string') {
    namespaces = [namespaces] as string[]
  }

  namespaces.concat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reassign this to a variable created with the `string[]` type:

```
let nss: string[];

if (typeof namespaces === 'string') {
  namespaces = [namespaces];
}
nss = namespaces;
```

You have another issue on this line:

```
ns[n] = (req.i18n.services.resourceStore.data[lang] || {})[ns] || {}
```

I think this should probably be

```
ns[n] = (req.i18n.services.resourceStore.data[lang] || {})[n] || {}
```

`ns` is an object so it can't be used as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Add `| undefined` to `namespaces` parameter

Consider do not mutate `namespaces` but create separate constant instaed

```
    const nss: string[] = !ns
    ? []
    : typeof ns === 'string'
        ? [ns]
        : ns
```